# c# new Process().Start() doesn't work on windows xp IIS 5.1

Tags: windows-xp, cmd

I am trying to change the system date and time using cmd. I can run the cmd manually with command prompt and it works. It doesn't work when IIS5.1/XP is hosting it. Here is the method I use to run the command.

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs a cmd and returns the response
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cmd"></param>
/// <returns>The respond of the cmd</returns>
private static string RunCmd(string cmd)
{
    var p = new Process();

    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", cmd)
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    p.WaitForExit();

    return cmd + Environment.NewLine + output;
}
```

This works as expected on my dev box (windows server 2008 r2) using both cassini and IIS7. Why doesn't it work on XP/IIS5.1? I suspect it is a permissions issue. If so, how do I get the default website in IIS5.1 full blow admin permissions?

Also, here he the code I use to call the previous mentioned method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the date.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="year">The year.</param>
/// <param name="month">The month.</param>
/// <param name="day">The day.</param>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public static string SetDate(int year, int month, int day)
{
    var date = month.ToString("##") + "-" + day.ToString("##") + "-" + year.ToString("####");
    return RunCmd("CMD /c DATE " + date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to take a look at the Standard Error? Maby you can see the reason why the call fails.